# Swift Error : 'DYLD_BOOL' is not convertible to 'bool'

Tags: swift, boolean

I am developing a simple tableview based application where If user touch at any cell then he will navigate to the DetailViewController and when user click on DetailViewController he goes back to the tableView for that I use:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(TRUE, completion: nil)
}
```

But I can not use true in small later and that line give me error like:

```
'DYLD_BOOL' is not convertible to 'bool'
```

What is the solution for this?

Comment: here's a link to the answer in another question :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26875335/1869369

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `true`, instead of `TRUE`.